# Why grep does not recognize the right curly bracket?

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I want to match a string like this:

```
\sf{text}
```

I wrote:

```
grep -rnw '.' --include \*.tex -o -e '\\sf{text}
```

but it does not return anything. However if i write

```
grep -rnw '.' --include \*.tex -o -e '\\sf{text
```

It returns the correct file.

Why is the right curly bracket not captured?

Comment: are you looking for a fixed text or something variable? some sample input would be helpful

Comment: i wrote the exact example. I am looking for \sf{text}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for a fixed string, you'd better use `-F` instead of `-e`:

```
grep -F '\sf{text}' files
```

This way you don't have to worry about escaping characters, special meaning, etc.

From `man grep`:

> **Matcher Selection**
>
> **-F**, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
>   any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

Whereas the one you were using, `-e`, uses the string as a pattern, hence the special meaning of it.

> **Matching Control**
>
> **-e** PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple
>   search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a  hyphen (-).
>   (-e is specified by POSIX.)

---

#### Update

> And how do i replace the matching pattern? in all the files that they
>   do contain this pattern delete it and replace it with another one.

I would use `find` to get the files and `sed` to replace the content.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/\\sf{text}/XXX/g' {} +
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
sdi
asd \sf{text} asdf
ads
$ sed 's/\\sf{text}/XXX/g' a
sdi
asd XXX asdf
ads
```

Note that the curly braces do not have to be escaped. Just the backslash.

Comment: It doesn't work either. There is an error even for my working example without the right curly bracket.grep: "\sf{text: No such file or directory"

Comment: I've "cleaned" the solution to just `-F`. The rest of the flags you were using it is not clear to me whether they are necessary or not (I need more info for it).

Comment: Ok but is there a more generic solution? as a pattern

Comment: If you are just looking for all the files containing this string, then use `grep -rF '\sf{text}' *`. Note this `*` is what was missing before.

Comment: And how do i replace the matching pattern?

Comment: @curious so given this pattern, you want to change it in all the files containing it?  Not sure about what you mean and it may be better to update the question with these details.

Comment: in all the files that they do contain this pattern delete it and replace it with another one

Comment: It seems that nothing changed even though baks were created

Comment: @curious strange. If you have exactly the text `\sf{text}` this should make it. Test it without `-i` (to see the output in the screen) in one specific file.

Comment: it just outputs the entire file

Comment: @curious I cannot find an explanation. Just updated with an example.